# Html signatures: how to prevent user editing

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, signatures, windows-live-mail

I have made some `.html` signatures for one of our clients, and there are two things they want I can't figure out how to achieve.

One of them, the client wants the **text inside the signature to not be editable** by the user, that is to prevent them from accidentally changing something in the signature when sending an e-mail. Is this somehow posible?

The second issue, they said **they can resize the images in the signature using the mouse. I also need to prevent this** so that they cannot accidentally deform the logo or enlarge or diminish it. How can I do it? I tried setting `width` and `height` attributes to the images, but that doesn't prevent them form resizing it at will.

Any help or orientation will be really much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can create an image with the entire signature, so it won't be editable.

**EDIT**

Take a look at this link, maybe you will be able to add the signature after the send button is click.

[How to  modify  email before sending](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/12/outlook-change-message-before-sending/)

Comment: I don't want to make the entire signature a image so that the e-mail receiver can copy-paste the contact data in the signature, and so that e-mail clients such as apple mail can allow to create a contact from the signature. Anyways, thanks for your answer. I will take a look at that link now.

Comment: Modifying the email before sending does not work for me because not all users have outlook, some of them have apple mail or windows live mail. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

1.) If you use an exchange server, you can set a Group Policy to add a signature server level and then another to remove permissions for signature access to all users.  This will give you 100% control on all Outgoing messages. This is supposed to be used for disclaimers, so in a long email chain, the signatures may wind up at the bottom of the chain, not the message. See for more info: http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm

2.) Another option is to run a script. This option steers away from using Group Policy, but I believe it would require action done on user level for each person, which may be an issue in a larger company.  See here for more info: http://www.edugeek.net/blogs/thescarfedone/1016-centrally-managing-signatures-outlook-owa-free-way.html

3.) Last option I know of is to make signatures folder read only and insert the signature file directly on each person's computer. This is a very manual process and time consuming and certainly not scalable. See here for more details: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-email-signatures-to-another-computer-4e03286f-2246-4d7d-ae95-a4cc1992595a?CorrelationId=0db01a3d-f8b9-4bfb-af86-37cd4dcf6ef9&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: About option 3: As signatures are html formatted, I do have to save each signature in every user's computer's hidden folders to enable outlook/applemail to use it. If I set these signatures files as read-only, that will prevent the user from accidentally modifying it when sending an email? Or it will only prevent it to be permantently modifyied from Signatures option? If this is the right way to go, is there any way I can do this for windows live mail too? Does it saves the signature files somewhere where I can set them as read-only? If I can do it this way this is the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Once it is in the email edit window, it can be edited. You would likely need to have it added at server level like option 1 in order to ensure it is not changed in the email edit window. You may want to look into either creating a script in VBA to create and add at server level, or using a third party service - http://www.slipstick.com/addins/disclaimer-signature-tools-for-exchange-server/